# Open final .pdf file generated by pdflatex through command line

Tags: pdftex

I have a program that generates .tex files and then compiles them using pdflatex through the Mac Terminal. I am simply using some python code to achieve the same effect as the following command:

```
pdflatex filename.tex
```

Is it possible to make pdflatex open the final pdf after it has finished generating it?

Comment: No, what should `pdflatex` do with the PDF once it is finished with it. You might want to ask your python script to ask the Mac to open the file in a PDF viewer. BTW: I usually use `latexmk -pdf -pv file.tex` for this (it is a PERL script that usually comes with MacTeX)

Comment: The command you're looking for is called [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html).

Comment: I use Skim as PDF viewer, which sports an “autorefresh” option for regenerated PDF files. Just open the PDF file with Skim (`open -a Skim <filename>.pdf`) and upon recompilation it will refresh (the first time you'll be asked if you want automatic refresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should ask your OS's PDF viewer to do that. Most PDFviewers (except Acrobat, afaik), allow you to update the pdf file while still open. See the comments to complete the answer.